systemctl status dbus: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyparsing'
I'm facing this issue when running systemctl status dbus on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS:
$ sudo systemctl status dbus
● dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-09-20 12:12:57 CEST; 12min ago
TriggeredBy: ● dbus.socket
       Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
   Main PID: 1050 (dbus-daemon)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38025)
     Memory: 5.1M
        CPU: 1.544s
     CGroup: /system.slice/dbus.service
             └─1050 @dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only

sep 20 12:20:32 username-ThinkPad-P15s com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[23869]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 25, in <module>
sep 20 12:20:32 username-ThinkPad-P15s com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[23869]:     from launchpadlib.launchpad import Launchpad
sep 20 12:20:32 username-ThinkPad-P15s com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[23869]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 36, in <module>
sep 20 12:20:32 username-ThinkPad-P15s com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[23869]:     from httplib2 import ProxyInfo
sep 20 12:20:32 username-ThinkPad-P15s com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[23869]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
sep 20 12:20:32 username-ThinkPad-P15s com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[23869]:     from . import auth
sep 20 12:20:32 username-ThinkPad-P15s com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[23869]:   File "/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/auth.py", line 4, in <module>
sep 20 12:20:32 username-ThinkPad-P15s com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[23869]:     import pyparsing as pp
sep 20 12:20:32 username-ThinkPad-P15s com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[23869]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyparsing'
sep 20 12:20:32 username-ThinkPad-P15s dbus-daemon[1050]: [system] Activated service 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties' failed: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1

and some system application don't start, e.g.
$ software-properties-gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 177, in activate_name_owner
    return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
    return self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties': no such name

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 210, in __init__
    proxy = bus.get_object("com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties", "/")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    return self.ProxyObjectClass(self, bus_name, object_path,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 250, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 182, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 277, in start_service_by_name
    return (True, self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1

I'm pretty sure it's because the Python package pyparsing is installed twice;

at the system level where it was certainly automatically installed:

$ apt-cache policy python3-pyparsing
python3-pyparsing:
  Installed: 2.4.7-1
  Candidate: 2.4.7-1

and the second, probably coming as a dependency with some packages that I installed manually in the /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages directory:
$ pip list -v | grep "Version\|pyparsing"
Package       Version      Location                                    Installer
------------- ------------ ------------------------------------------- ---------
pyparsing     3.0.9        /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages     pip

Those other packages are:
$ pip show pyparsing | grep ^Required-by
Required-by: httplib2, matplotlib, snuggs

Because pyparsing exists twice, Ubuntu should never complain about "not finding it"! 
How could I tell Ubuntu's applications and system tasks to make use of the Python package directory installed by its own apt package management system before the one in the directory /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages?
